# Where is task.Response being set

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I'm implementing a basic authentication handler, I create a on the `ContinueWith` method the task result is always a 401 unauthorized. Where does this value get set? Should I set it earlier?

```
var resp = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
    .ContinueWith(
        task =>
        {                     
            response = task.Result;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                && !response.Headers.Contains(BasicAuthResponseHeader))
            {
                response.Headers.Add(
                    BasicAuthResponseHeader, 
                    BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue);
            }
            WasHttpExceptionThrown(response.Content);

            return response;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, use `await` *instead of* `ContinueWith`:

```
var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
    && !response.Headers.Contains(BasicAuthResponseHeader))
{
  response.Headers.Add(
      BasicAuthResponseHeader, 
      BasicAuthResponseHeaderValue);
}
WasHttpExceptionThrown(response.Content);
```

This ensures that your code remains in the request context.